# Context and Provider not accessible via Modal

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I do not control the modal components in my company. The I am using redux-toolkit so I am wondering if this is the issue.  I have tried a few different iterations trying to get this to work and tried mimicing another app that it works with (standard redux app).

The below code is me trying to mimic the other app that has it working.

my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'proxima-nova/scss/proxima-nova.scss'
import './css/styles.scss';
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RcReducer } from './Store/RC/Events';
import { RcDataReducer } from './Store/RC/RcData';

const middleware = [...getDefaultMiddleware()];

export const ReduxStore = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        RcEvents: RcReducer,
        RcData: RcDataReducer,
    },
    middleware,
});

ReactDOM.render(<App store={ReduxStore} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

My app.tsx

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Wrapper from './Components/Wrapper/Wrapper';
import './App.scss';
import Loader from './Components/Common/Loader/Loader';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import StoreProvider from './Store/Store';

const Home = lazy(() => import('./Components/Pages/Home/Home'));
const RcDashboard = lazy(() => import('./Components/Pages/RC/RC'));
const EccDashboard = lazy(() => import('./Components/Pages/ECC/Dashboard/Dashboard'));

const App: React.FunctionComponent<{ store: any }> = ({ store }: { store: any }) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <StoreProvider>
                <Router>
                    <div id='root'>
                        <Wrapper>
                            <Suspense fallback={<Loader overlay={true} fullscreen={false} size='xl' />}>
                                <Switch>
                                    <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
                                    <Route path='/rc' component={RcDashboard} />
                                    <Route path='/ecc' exact component={EccDashboard} />
                                </Switch>
                            </Suspense>
                        </Wrapper>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </StoreProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

I am calling a component that is provided for use within my company. I personally do not have control over how this component acts. It is a modal. The modal does not just append itself to the component it is called in and automatically appends itself to the body tag.

For some reason the neither my context nor my redux store are showing up. I instead get this.

[image]

I am currently at a loss as to how I can get this working. I appreciate any help provided.

Comment: Your entire app(including the provider) is wrapped inside the DOM Node with the id app. However, since your modal is appending itself to the body, it  is outside the context of your react application and hence, cannot access the store.

Comment: Thanks, this was my assumption as well. That is why I mentioned another team is using the same tech except using standard redux and not redux toolkit and it is working. I can import the modal component from the same library and connect it with redux either through hooks or connect. Is there any way to get this working to where I don't have to wrap a separate provider around the inner workings of a my modal content as that would not be ideal.

Comment: I should also note that my app is being rendered directly on the body element and not div with id of app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that that modal if somehow forwarding the context value, but probably only legacy context. So it might work with an older version or react-redux, but not with a current one.

You'll have to either use a Portal in the modal instead of creating a completely new ReactDOM instance (which is probably happening right now) or forward the current value to a new  in the modal, like this

```
function YourComponent(){
  const store = useStore()

  return <Modal><Provider store={store}>whatEverGoesIntoYourModal</Provider></Modal>
}
```

Comment: This might work. I was hoping to not have to do that as a whole but it might just be the only way. Looking at the modal code it isn't creating a portal. This other project that has it working is not wrapping secondary providers so I assumed that I am missing something (waiting for someone on that team to respond as well as using stack overflow). Depending I will mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, Legacy context could just be forwarded as a whole so I guess that is what that Modal is doing internally. The new 16.3+ context cannot do that.I'd suggest rewriting the Modal with a Portal, as that will solve all context-related issues for good.

Comment: So it seems that team created a patch in their project to fix the issue. So that being said your answer is correct. Thanks.